# How to allocate DMA channel in user space?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, dma

I am the maintainer of an [open source project that relies on the DMA controller to do PWM on Raspberry Pi IO pins](https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster). This technique requires the use of one DMA channel. We have historically hard-coded the DMA channel 0 but got multiple bug reports stating that the program does not work properly when X is running at the same time (bug reports: [here](https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster/issues/16) and [here](https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster/issues/27), [etc](https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster/issues)).

We have found the [Mailbox API](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/wiki/Mailbox-property-interface) in the Raspberry PI firmware which includes an API to manage shared resources such as DMA channels and figure out which ones are available.

Pattrick Hueper [gave this a try](https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster/pull/38#discussion_r28041695) but it still reports channel 0 as available. Maybe X does not use this API to announce which channel it is using.

I found `dma_request_channel()` for kernel space programs but that is not available in user space.

What is the proper way to use a DMA channel from user space while being a good citizen on the computer and avoid conflict with other tools?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to confirm the following:

You include:

```
#include <mach/dma.h>

...
int rc = bcm_dma_chan_alloc(
  BCM_DMA_FEATURE_NORMAL,  /* Features found in mach/dma.h */
  &dma_base,
  &dma_irq
);
```

rc is returned negative, if an error occurs. When rc >= 0, it is the dma channel 
returned.

```
void __iomem *dma_base; /* returned */
int dma_irq;            /* returned */
```

To release:

```
bcm_dma_chan_free(dma_chan);
```

So far, it has returned me DMA channel 2:

```
[   99.372778] chan = rc = 2, dma_base=f3007200, IRQ=77
[   99.372790] Returned DMA channel 2.
[  103.971670] Releasing DMA Channel 2
```

and 4 (when I left DMA 2 unreleased).